# Change the position of minimize/maximize/close window buttons from upper right corner to upper left corner in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, window-buttons

The minimize, maximize, and close buttons used to be in the upper left corner of windows, which I prefer because most of the content in the windows I use is on the left side, so it takes less mouse movement to get to the upper left corner.

Why was this changed? Is there a way to move those buttons to the upper left corner?

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi That link is about Unity. This question is about GNOME. [Ubuntu 17.10 switched from Unity to GNOME](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/ubuntu-17-10-return-of-the-gnome/).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Sorry, didn't see the tag! In that case, this seems to answer the question: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348381&p=13590512#post13590512